# Как изменить цвет SelectedItem (в ListBox)?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Имеется следующий ListBox

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxQuestionAnswers" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Question.Answers}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="ListBoxQuestionAnswers_OnSelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockInListBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Где Question.Answers - List типа string. Нужно в обработчике нажатия на элемент ListBox менять цвет выбранного элемента.
Сейчас код обработчика выглядит так:

```
private void ListBoxQuestionAnswers_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBoxQuestionAnswers.SelectedIndex == Question.CorrectAnswerIndex)
        {
            Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green); 
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }

    }
```

Проблема в том, что таким образом меняется цвет выбранных элементов во всем приложении. Как сделать так, чтобы цвет SelectedItem менялся только в этом ListBox?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 if (ListBoxQuestionAnswers.SelectedIndex == Question.CorrectAnswerIndex)
{
    ListBoxQuestionAnswers.Resources ["SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Green);
    ListBoxQuestionAnswers.Resources ["SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Green);
}
else
{
    ListBoxQuestionAnswers.Resources ["SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Red);
    ListBoxQuestionAnswers.Resources ["SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Red);
}
```

Comment: Это повлияет также на все другие элементы, в которых используются эти ресурсы.

Answer (score 1):

Кликните правой кнопкой мыши по своему `ListBox` в дизайнере и выберите меню "Edit Additional Templates" - "Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle)" - "Edit a Copy...", после чего дайте вменяемое название шаблону в появившемся окошке и нажмите "OK". Студия добавит стандартный шаблон для `ListBoxItemContainer` в проект, отредактируйте его. Вас интересуют `VisualState` с названиями `SelectedUnfocused`, `SelectedPointerOver`, `SelectedPressed` и возможно еще некоторые другие, отредактируйте в них значение `Value` у `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` в `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`с `Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground`:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Pink"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Answer (score -1):

Если вам нужно просто изменить цвет выделенного значения, то создайте простой [ListBox.ItemContainerStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) стиль, примерно такой:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="listStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="5"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Поясню:

- `<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="listStyle">` - тут мы указываем тип, к которому стиль будет применим (в нашем случае это ListBoxItem), а также мы тут указываем ключ (key) для того, что бы стиль использовался только тогда, когда нам понадобится.
- `<Setter Property="Template">` - тут мы указываем, что хотим задать другой вид нашего ListBoxItem.
- `<Border Background="...` - мы оборачиваем наш ListBoxItem в Bordel, который в свою очередь получает Background и другие значения от тех, что укажем мы в стиле.
- `<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">` - это тригер, который сработает в момент, когда IsSekected будет True (то есть значение выбрано). Ну и внутри мы меняем то, что нам хочется (в данном случае цвет текста и задний фон).

Все, остается только применить стиль к нужному ListBox: `ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource listStyle}"`.

Результат:

[image: result]

Comment: Увы, но это актуально для WPF. В UWP триггеров просто нет

Comment: @tayabuz Да, вы правы, попробуйте там использовать заместо тригеров `<VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">`. [Подробнее](https://metanit.com/sharp/uwp/10.2.php) [Пример](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7f91dfdb-41cc-42ca-9635-7666c1b99813/uwpxaml-change-background-color-of-listbox-selected-item?forum=wpdevelop)